# How to select anchor elements by condition (contains multiple substring) using BeautifulSoup - Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
page_request = requests.get("https://example.com/some-page")
page_html_parse = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_request.text, "html.parser")

class_abc_anchors = page_html_parse.findAll("a", {"class":"abc"})

for i in class_abc_anchors:
    print(i)
```

When I run it, it prints:

```
<a class="abc" href="http://example.com/apple-is-fruit"> Apple </a>
<a class="abc" href="http://example.com/orange-is-fruit"> Orange </a>
<a class="abc" href="http://example.com/apple-and-orange-are-fruits"> Both </a>
```

From the above result, I want to get the only anchor which contains both 'apple' and 'orange' string in its **href** tag.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you really mean "and" rather than "or" ?

Comment: Yes, I meant and.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting directly by condition you can use `css selectors` to check, if substrings are in `href` attribute:

```
soup.select('a[href*="orange"] + a[href*="apple"]')
```

or more specific incl. class:

```
soup.select('a.abc[href*="orange"] + a.abc[href*="apple"]')

##output
[<a class="abc" href="http://example.com/apple-and-orange-are-fruits"> Both </a>]
```

---

#### Alternative

Use `all()` to check against a list of your conditions while iterating your `ResultSet`:

```
all(x in a['href'] for x in ['apple','orange'])
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<a class="abc" href="http://example.com/apple-is-fruit"> Apple </a>
<a class="abc" href="http://example.com/orange-is-fruit"> Orange </a>
<a class="abc" href="http://example.com/apple-and-orange-are-fruits"> Both </a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
matches = ['apple','orange']
for a in soup.select('a'):
    if all(x in a['href'] for x in matches):
        print(a['href])
```

#### Output

```
http://example.com/apple-and-orange-are-fruits
```